# to read br or pre or html tag in angular expression json data

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

```js
/* sentence = "sdf vfgfhgjhkj,k ghhjjhjhjhj fgghghghgvvvv
              ssdfgbghg vvffffffffffffffffffffffffbbbfbfffffffff
              ccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc"
```

```html
<table class="table-responsive">
 <th>notice</th>
<tr ng-repeat stment in data.note.statements>
  <td>{{stment.sentence}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I want the angular expression to bind json data as it is with line-breaks coming as it is.

Answer (score 0):

first split the long sentence with `\n`:

```
$scope.displayData = $scope.data.note.statements.split('\n');
```

then display the split data in TABLE

```
 <table class="table-responsive">
      <th>notice</th>
      <tr ng-repeat="item in displayData">
           <td>{{item}}</td>
      </tr>
 </table>
```

Comment: \n is not there I want to use pre tag

Answer (score 0):

Manish,

Not sure it will work but try using: ng-bind-html

```
<table class="table-responsive">
 <th>notice</th>
<tr ng-repeat="stment in data.note.statements">
  <td ng-bind-html="'<pre>' + stment.sentence + '</pre>'"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: you can also alter the string ahead of time just create a variable like $scope.strArray = []
for (var i in $scope.data.note.statements) {
strArray.push('<pre>' + data.note.statements[i] + '</pre>')
}

Comment: Then just ng-repeat="statement in strArray"

Comment: and ng-bind-html="statement" on the <td>